# Running MFmask in MATLAB: Error using imfill

Tags: remote-sensing, error, landsat-8, masking, matlab

I am trying to create a cloud and cloud shadow masking raster using MFmask (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425717303073) for a Landsat 8 scene. MFmask 1.1 is modified version of Fmask 3.3 for better detection of cloud shadow in mountainous region using DEM. Previously I run Fmask 3.3 standalone and that worked, but the cloud/cloud shadow detection wasn't good enough and I moved to MFmask. It has no standalone, thus it has been run through MATLAB, but I got following error during the running in MATLAB.

```
>> addpath('D:\INSTALL\Cloud detection\MFmask\MFmask-master\MFmask-master\MFmask_1_1_beta')
>> autoMFmask

MFmask 1.1 version start.
Cloud, cloud shadow, and snow detection for Landsat 8 imagery.
Cloud/cloud shadow/snow dilated by 3/3/0 pixels (default).
Cloud probability threshold of 22.50% (default).
Loading input data.
From DNs to TOA ref & BT
Detecting clouds. This might take some minutes so be patient.
Error using imfill
Expected input number 1, I1 or BW1, to be non-NaN.

Error in imfill>parse_inputs (line 165)
validateattributes(IM, {'numeric' 'logical'}, {'nonsparse' 'real','nonnan'}, ...

Error in imfill (line 123)
[I,locations,conn,do_fillholes] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Error in plshadow2 (line 27)
    data_nir_filled=imfill(data_nir);

Error in plcloud_ratelapse2 (line 228)
        Shadow=plshadow2( data_nir,data_swir,idlnd,mask,l_pt,...

Error in MFmask (line 5)
        =plcloud_ratelapse2(fullfile_path,im,demtype,cldprob,num_Lst);

Error in autoMFmask (line 108)
    clr_pct = MFmask(fullfile_path,norMTL.name,demtype,cldpix,sdpix,snpix,cldprob,num_Lst,num_near,gap_off); % newest version
    1.1
```

How can I handle these issues? Such errors could be found during running of Fmask as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is because Matlab imfill function cannot process Nan value. Anyway, this bug has been fixed in the MFmask. Everyone can download the MFmask package at https://github.com/qsly09/MFmask. Thank you.